# How to vote in polling system?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

these are my POCO classes :

```
public class PollOptions
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Polls Polls { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public int Votes { get; set; }
    }
public class Polls
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PollOptions> PollOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have passed my model this way to Index view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var poll = db.Polls.Include("PollOptions").Where(x => x.Active).ToList();
           return View(model);
        }
```

and in Index view I want to that users vote and below
is my section for poll :

```
@section Polling{
   @foreach (var question in Model.Polls)
    {
        <h3>@question.Question</h3>
       <ul class="pollUnordedList">
       @foreach(var answer in question.PollOptions)
        {
            <li><input type="radio" name="opt" id="@answer.Id" value="1"/><span>@answer.Answer</span></li>
        }
        </ul>
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Radio", controllerName: "Home",routeValues: new { id = 2, value = 5 }))
    {
        <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="ارسال نظر" /></p>
    }
}
```

My action Method :

```
public void Radio(int Id=0,int value=0)
       {
           PollOptions opt = db.PollOptions.Find(Id);
           db.Entry(opt).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
           opt.Votes += value;
           db.SaveChanges();
       }
```

How can I get value and id of radioButton for pass as route Values, for example in above route Values for Id and value are 2,5

Comment: Regarding `value="1"`, is this value always equal to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using jQuery AJAX :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Radio", controllerName: "Home")) {
        foreach (var question in Model.Polls)
        {
            <h3>@question.Question</h3>
            <ul class="pollUnordedList">
                @foreach (var answer in question.PollOptions)
                {
                    <li>
                        @*@Html.RadioButton("options",false,new {id=@answer.Id})<span>@answer.Answer</span>*@
                        @Html.RadioButton("options",answer.Id)<span>@answer.Answer</span>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        }
         <p>
            <input type="submit" id="btnVote" class="btn btn-primary" value="ارسال نظر" />
        </p>
    }
```

and my action method :

```
[HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Radio(int options)
       {
           var option = db.PollOptions.Find(options);
           if (option != null) option.Votes++;
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
```

thanks Daniel Liuzzi, there is'nt need to foreach because if radio button is selected, the value of radio button that is submitted when the form is posted.

Comment: Unless your view only has a single radio button, you definitely need the `foreach` loop. When your form is posted, *all radio buttons* are posted, and this translates to an array on your action method, as explained in the second comment of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same name for all your radio buttons:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Radio", controllerName: "Home")) {
    foreach (var question in Model.Polls) {
        <h3>@question.Question</h3>
        foreach (var answer in question.PollOptions) {
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="answers" value="@answer.Id" />
                @answer.Answer
            </label>
        }
    }

    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="ارسال نظر" /></p>
}
```

Then on your action method, you receive selected answers as an array:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Radio(int[] answers)
{
    // TODO: Save your answers
}
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment about value always being equal to 1, then there is no point in passing it. You just *assume* a value of 1 for every selected radio button. Your action method then looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Radio(int[] answers)
{
    foreach (var id in answers)
    {
        var option = db.PollOptions.Find(id);
        if (option != null) option.Votes++;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you post multiple radio buttons with the same name, they are posted as, for example,`answers=1&answers=2&answers=9&answers=17&...` (the name is repeated for each one of your selected radios.) MVC Model binding then converts this into an array such as `answers = { 1, 2, 9, 17, ... }` You can then do a `foreach` loop on this array to save selected answers to the DB.

Comment: tnx, but I do not know how can I pass them via HTML.BeginForm, Can you explain that?

Comment: I have now added `Html.BeginForm` to the sample. Notice how your radio buttons all need to be *inside* the form; otherwise their values won't get posted.

Comment: as I told, I want to post two parameters to my method: 1)Id 2)Vote because via id I can Update vote(vote is 1 in fact it is like a counter) in my table.

Comment: I'm afraid your description wasn't clear then. Looking at the code sample you provided, you first have have a collection of *questions* which in turn have each a collection of *options*. I don't know where votes come from. The only mention of vote in your post (other than the title) is that `opt.Votes += value` which I'm not sure what it does. Sorry but it's not clear. If you can update your question and explain yourself in more consistent terms, I might be able to better understand you and offer you further advice.